# Get first weekday name of each month in a year

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to create a vector which contains the first day of each month from the year 2015.

My attempt to do this:

```
start_2015 <- ymd_hms("2015-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "America/New_York")

Labels <- rep(0, 12)
for(i in 0:11){
    Labels[i+1] = wday(start_2015 + months(i), label = T )
}
```

I get this output but it doesn't keep the labels

```
> Labels
 [1] 5 1 1 4 6 2 4 7 3 5 1 3
```

What I wanted was this:

```
Labels_2 <-  c(wday(start_2015 + months(0), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(1), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(2), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(3), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(4, label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(5), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(6), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(7), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(8), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(9), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(10), label = T ),
               wday(start_2015 + months(11), label = T ))
> Labels_2
 [1] Thu Sun Sun Wed Fri Mon Wed Sat Tue Thu Sun Tue
Levels: Sun < Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat
```

But I don't understand why the loop does not produce this output.

Comment: You are seeing the “labels” attributes of a single value (Sun)  of an ordered factor value. We can assist you better if you describe your goals more completely. If you want an ordered factor then say so.

Comment: `format(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-01"), by = "month"), "%a")`

Comment: @IRTFM I clarified what I wanted in the post. I'd like the ordered factor but I am not sure what my loop doesn't produce that.

Comment: You don't need a loop, the functions used are vectorized. `wday(ymd("2015-01-01") + months(0:11), label = TRUE)` (or the `base` code above)